# What style checking does -gnatyo actually perform?

Tags: ada, gnat

The [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gnat_ugn_unw/Style-Checking.html#Style-Checking) reads:

> Check order of subprogram bodies. If the letter o appears in the string after -gnaty then all subprogram bodies in a given scope (e.g. a package body) must be in alphabetical order. The ordering rule uses normal Ada rules for comparing strings, ignoring casing of letters, except that if there is a trailing numeric suffix, then the value of this suffix is used in the ordering (e.g. Junk2 comes before Junk10).

I take it that `Junk2` coming for `Junk10` is the actual inspiration for an otherwise odd style enforcement. But what's an example of some code that actually triggers it? I couldn't get this option to complain with disordered function definitions or task bodies. For example, I get no complaints when compiling the following with `gnat make -gnatyo`:

```ada
procedure Disordered is
   function Test return Natural;
   function Zest return Natural;

   --  disordered function bodies
   function Zest return Natural is (1);
   function Test return Natural is (2);
begin
   null;
end Disordered;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

```ada
   --  disordered function bodies
   function Zest return Natural is (1);
   function Test return Natural is (2);
```

but technically, these are not subprogram bodies. They are called expression functions. The reason for this clear separation is that subprogram bodies are not allowed in package specifications, whereas expression functions are.
Using actual subprogram bodies in your example will give the expected style warning:

```ada
   function Zest return Natural is 
   begin
      return 1;
   end Zest;

   function Test return Natural is
   begin
      return 2;
   end Test;
```

(and since you mentioned task bodies; those are also not subprogram bodies)

Comment: I think that not requiring ordering of expression functions might be an oversight

Comment: Maybe. The style check was definitely implemented before expression functions existed, so there's a fair chance... However,that would possibly require them to always be completions of previous declarations, as they could have inter-dependencies requiring a different ordering